# Android Support Library Setup error

Tags: android, gradle

I followed instruction from http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html to add the support library to my android project, but got an build error like this

Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':projectname'.

> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+]
>     Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)

Does anyone know the reason for that? Is it a syntax error in gradle? Below is a piece of code in my build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should add it in the main "dependencies" section, the one you find at the bottom of your build.gradle file and not under "buildscript".

Comment: Right, 'appcompat-v7:18.0.+' should be placed outside of your buildscript block.

Answer (score 11):

This should be like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
        // this is for Gradle build system so it finds
        // android plugin used below
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    // this is for your application
}
```

Don't forget to install Android Support Repository in Android SDK Manager.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH., I notice there are TWO build.gradle files in Android Studio. There seems to be one at the "top" level ("AppName") and then one in a folder, ("AppName-AppName") ...  **which one** do I change?!

Comment: @JoeBlow You should change the "AppName-AppName" one.